# How does one become Muslim as a Woman?

Tags: conversion, helping

[image]

I am looking to understand this process for myself...

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Here some related links: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/how-would-i-convert-to-islam-and-become-a-muslim, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/156/how-does-one-convert-to-islam-from-another-religion and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25265/what-should-a-couple-in-a-civil-union-do-when-converting-to-islam if you still have questions please consider editing your post using the edit-link at the bottom left.

Comment: Why the picture though?

Comment: The picture to me, is how I feel when speaking of this topic ...